# Problemas con JavaFX al conectar el JDBC

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jdbc

Estoy usando Eclipse para realizar una interfaz grafica con JavafX, todo funciona bien pero cuando añado el .Jar de MySQL conector al proyecto me sale este error al iniciarla interfaz grafica:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

El conector en el SceneBuilder esta funcionando correctamente porque si elimino la libreria me muestra la ventana con la GUI que cree.

Gracias por las respuestas

Comment: Te está diciendo claramente que falta este módulo: `javafx.controls`. Si piensas usarlo debes incluir el .jar o, si usas Maven incluirlo en el `pom.xml`  o si usas Gradle incluirlo al estilo de Gradle.